# How to make a price display within a circle with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.special-price {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2e566e;
}

.special-price .offer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #56c243;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.offer .symbol {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.offer .dollars {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.offer .cents {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="special-price col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="general-comparison clearfix">
      <div class="offer">
        <sup class="symbol">$</sup><span class="dollars">34</span><sup class="cents">.99</sup><span class="tax">+ TAX</span>
      </div>
      <!-- end .general-comparison -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question/Issue**

1. Why is the dollar sign going outside the circle?
2. I have set the parent container's `text-align:center` so why is the child element `offer` not centered within the parent element `special-price`?

I am open to other suggestions, I just want this to look nice but unfortunately I am not a designer.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vw5nw7jk/) in case you want to see a demo.

Comment: remove the vertical-align:top you defined and add this to the circle `padding-top: 34px;
    box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks but then the $ symbol and the cents will not be at the top and looks odd.

Comment: consider line-height to align also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css) has a variety of techniques for vertically centering text.

I added another div `price` within the offer, as the offer was really representing the bubble so trying to position the text within it is harder without it's own context.

```
<div class="offer">
  <div class="price">
    <sup class="symbol">$</sup><span class="dollars">34</span><sup class="cents">.99</sup><span class="tax">+ TAX</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LfaL90qc/).  I also made the text a bit larger and put the +TAX on a new line to break things up a bit.

Comment: That is great, this will do for now. I like the fact you made another div for the price.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the price and unit later here is a version with splitted content. Otherwise you also could put the Dollar unit and cents into the before and after pseudos.

I like to use the flex for stuff like this. `display: flex; align-items: center;` centers the content in vertical and horizontal in the section circle. the `display: flex;` in p tag centers the sup tags on horizontal.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.price {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  }

.price, .price * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
    
.price p {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 .price p sup {
  font-size: 12px;
 }
```

```html
<section class='price'>
  <p>
  <sup>$</sup>
  34
  <sup>.99</sup>
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix these issues you can add

`line-height: 2.6;` to `.special-price .offer`

and change `vertical-align` to `middle` in both `.offer .symbol` and `.offer .cents`.

That should do the trick.
Just play with the value of `line-height` as you wish to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Changing to `middle` makes it look weird. I need it to line up with the top of the dollars figure.